# Can I find out if no threads are waiting for a Semaphore?

Tags: c#, .net

My application deals with many simultaneous downloads. I only allow 3 download threads to run at the time, the other downloads are queued waiting for a semaphore.

**Code:**

```
private static Semaphore semPool = new Semaphore(3, 3);
private static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

X number of downloads waiting to be run:

```
semPool.WaitOne();
DownloadItem d = new DownloadItem(fileInfo, cts.Token, launchAfterDownload);
//wait for download to be complete
semPool.Release()
```

Now, what I want to be able to do is have a method to cancel all downloads. I do this by setting cts.Token as cancelled, but I want to then reset cts.Token when all current (and waiting) downloads are cancelled.

That is, I want to wait until semPool has 3 units.

```
public static void CancelAllDownloads()
{
    cts.Cancel();
    //wait until semPool has 3
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
}
```

If I call CancelAllDownloads() as it looks now, the 3 downloads running will be cancelled but the ones waiting will run since the cancellation token is reset. I want all the waiting ones to be cancelled too, *then* reset the cancellation token.

Comment: You could't use a IsCanceled member or static, that is set to true if CancelAllDownloads is being called and that is checked after semPool.WaitOne() is called. You can make this secure by using a lock object. If it's set, simply return from your thread because it has not started downloading anything at this moment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to use the [SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx) Class instead.

This class has the functionality that you are asking for, using it you could cancel all of the current download processes, both runnning and waiting. The code would then look something like:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim semPool = new SemaphoreSlim(3, 3);

semPool.Wait(cts.Token);

public static void CancelAllDownloads()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
```